# Nested-form is forbidden right? Then how to do this?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have project similar to this example.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  // Delete using id
}

if (isset($_POST['deleteAll'])) {
  // Delete using array name check
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validate()"> // First form
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validate()> // Second form
            <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        </form>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" value="Delete checked items" />
</form>
```

`onsubmit` used to use confirm function in `javascript`.

I already think about this and only can think to use `nested-form`.

`second form` and `submit delete` used to `delete` using `ID`.

`first form` and `submit deleteAll` used to `delete` all checked items.

if I `delete second form`,

and I click `delete` the `id` will be the `last index` of `foreach`.

So I will `delete` the last `row`, not the `row` I wanted to `delete`.

I already thinking and found no clue,

I hope someone here can give a clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to do it that way. You're just making it more complicated. A single form should suffice.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
      <button name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</button><br/>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" value="Delete checked items" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
// handle single delete
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $id = $_POST['delete']; // individual ID
}

// handle mulitple selected checkboxes
if(isset($_POST['deleteAll'])) {
  $ids = $_POST['check'];
}
```

Comment: Your way is more beautiful. Maybe I'm thinking to much, I'll try your way first.